# How do I translate a product description that is using the function getdescription to show the product description on the screen in 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, localisation

I have my product descriptions being shown using the `getDescription` function, and I just want to translate the text from English to French

Answer (score 1):

edit the product in the backend, select from the top left selector your french store, uncheck the checkbox "use default value" beside the description textarea, fill in your french text and save.

Comment: Do I have to do this for every product or will it apply to to all of them, and I then just have to fill in my respective french translations

Comment: you have to do it for every product

Comment: Hey Marius out of interest can you translate product descriptions through a themes translate csv?

Comment: theoretically, you may be able to do it, but it's not a good approach.